# Creating features from a list of variables in R

Tags: r, text, feature-extraction

I have a list of words from the [Yelp Academic Dataset](https://www.yelp.com/academic_dataset) and I'm trying to create a list of features for a model from them. I want to have a dummy variable indicating the presence/absence of each word in this list.

Example:

The review *The oldish man who owns the store is as sweet as can be.  Perhaps sweeter than the cookies or ice cream,* for example, would first get frequent words filtered out and stemmed. Let's say this leaves *oldish*, *sweet*, *ice*, and *cream*. I'd like R to automatically generate a new dummy variable for `hasOldish`, `hasSweet`, `hasIce`, and `hasCream`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Look into regular expressions (`? regex`). Beyond that, without some example data and the code you've thought up so far, it's pretty challenging to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Thomas you should try something or at least show what you have tried. Here I am using `tm` package.

```
txt <- "The oldish man who owns the store is as sweet as can be. Perhaps sweeter than the cookies or ice cream "

library(tm)
## create a corpus
dd = Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
scanner <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(x," "))
## define controls
## scanner to split words
## and dictionary since you ar looking only for special words
ctrl <- list(tokenize = scanner,
             stemming = TRUE,
             dictionary=c('oldish','sweet','ice','cream'))
termFreq(dd[[1]], control = ctrl)

oldish  sweet    ice  cream 
     1      1      1      1 
attr(,"class")
[1] "term_frequency" "integer"
```

Comment: You interpreted my problem correctly. This is the situation I'm referring to.